# Echo / Print works for an object string child, but not elsewhere

Tags: php, string, object

```
$s = $testObj->str;
```

// hypothetical

```
echo $s
```

// works

however

```
$out = "foo" . $s . "bar;
echo $out;
```

doesn't

tried () typecasting and strval, can't really think of anything else to do

Comment: do a `var_dump( $s )` see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in 2nd string. Should be:

```
$out = "foo" . $s . "bar";
echo $out;
```

Answer (score 1):

actually you can do

```
$str = "foo{$testObj->str}bar";
echo $str;
```

here .. a testcase : http://codepad.viper-7.com/8PCCkK